# error for integration of jsp and hibernate and spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

i want to to integrate spring jsf hibernate. i use maven and eclipse. but i have error.
would you please help me.
applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

 <!-- Beans Declaration -->
 <bean id="customer" class="model.Customer"/>

<!-- CustomerBo Declaration -->
 <bean id="CustomerBoImpl" class="bo.CustomerBoImpl">
      <property name="customerDaoImpl" ref="CustomerDaoImpl" />
     </bean>


 <!-- Customer DAO Declaration -->
 <bean id="CustomerDaoImpl" class="dao.CustomerDaoImpl">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
 </bean>

 <!-- Data Source Declaration -->
 <bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
  <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@Mohsen-PC:1521:mydb" />
  <property name="user" value="system" />
  <property name="password" value="123" />
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
  <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
  <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
 </bean>

 <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
 <bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
  <property name="annotatedClasses">
   <list>
    <value>model.Customer</value>
   </list>
  </property>
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

 <!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
       <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Customermanagedbean

```
@ManagedBean(name="CustomerMB")
@RequestScoped
public class Customermanagedbean implements Serializable{
@ManagedProperty(value="#{CustomerBoImpl}")
ICustomerBo customerBoImpl;
List<Customer> CustomerList;
public int customerId;
public String name;
public String address;
public String createdDate;



public ICustomerBo getCustomerBoImpl() {
    return customerBoImpl;
}
public void setCustomerBoImpl(ICustomerBo customerBoImpl) {
    this.customerBoImpl = customerBoImpl;
}

public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {
    return CustomerList;
}
public void setCustomerList(List<Customer> customerList) {
    CustomerList = customerList;
}
public int getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}
public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public String getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}
public void setCreatedDate(String createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}


}
```

CustomerBoImpl.java

```
public class CustomerBoImpl implements ICustomerBo{

    ICustomerDao customerDao;

    public void setCustomerDao(ICustomerDao customerDao) {
        this.customerDao = customerDao;
    }

    public ICustomerDao getCustomerDao() {
        return customerDao;
    }

    public void addCustomer(Customer customer){

        getCustomerDao().addCustomer(customer);

    }

    public void updateCustomer(Customer customer){
        getCustomerDao().updateCustomer(customer);
    }

    public void deleteCustomer(Customer customer){
        getCustomerDao().deleteCustomer(customer);
    }
    public List<Customer> findAllCustomer(){

        return getCustomerDao().findAllCustomer();
    }
}
```

CustomerDaoImpl.java

```
public class CustomerDaoImpl implements ICustomerDao{
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;}
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
         this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public void addCustomer(Customer customer){ 
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(customer);

    }

    public void updateCustomer(Customer customer){
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().update(customer);
    }

    public void deleteCustomer(Customer customer){
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().delete(customer);
    }


    public List<Customer> findAllCustomer(){

        List list = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession

().createQuery("from CUSTOMER").list();
        return list;

    }
}
```

errors:

```
initWebApplicationContext
    SEVERE: Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CustomerBoImpl' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'customerDaoImpl' of bean class [bo.CustomerBoImpl]: Bean property 'customerDaoImpl' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1396)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'customerDaoImpl' of bean class [bo.CustomerBoImpl]: Bean property 'customerDaoImpl' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1064)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:924)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
        ... 23 more

    Jul 01, 2012 4:54:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CustomerBoImpl' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'customerDaoImpl' of bean class [bo.CustomerBoImpl]: Bean property 'customerDaoImpl' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1396)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'customerDaoImpl' of bean class [bo.CustomerBoImpl]: Bean property 'customerDaoImpl' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1064)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:924)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
        ... 23 more
```

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ApplicationContext.xml, you have

```
<!-- CustomerBo Declaration -->
 <bean id="CustomerBoImpl" class="bo.CustomerBoImpl">
      <property name="customerDaoImpl" ref="CustomerDaoImpl" />
     </bean>
```

But the `CustomerBoImpl` class does not have a field with that name.  It instead has `customerDao`.